# How can I see the history of a merged branch in Eclipse using SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using Eclipse Helios with Subversive as SVN connector. When I merge back a branch into the trunk, I cannot access the history that happened inside the branch anymore. I can still see it using TortoiseSVN within Windows Explorer, so the history is still available in SVN itself. But is there any way to display the full "merged" history of an item from within Eclipse? Would subclipse offer such a feature?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Subversive here, but with Subclipse you normally see all branches in the SVN repositories view, unless you explicitly delete them. But even then, you can restore it by creating a new branch off the last revision for this branch before it has been deleted, then you can navigate trough it and see history in SVN repositories view.

Comment: But it means that I have to manually navigate into the branch. The items's history of the branch won't show up when I view the history of the item from within the trunk after the branch has been merged back into the trunk. Is this correct?